# Magento - Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Http:_Helper'

Tags: php, magento, mage

A fatal error apperead in all the web pages:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Http:_Helper' not found in
>   /web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/app/Mage.php on line 521

The error is related to the function below:

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    if (strpos($name, '/') === false) {
        $name .= '/data';
    }

    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

Where line 521 is:

```
self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
```

Below the log warning:

```
2012-11-26T22:27:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Http:/Helper.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-11-26T22:27:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage/Http:/Helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='/web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/app/code/local:/web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/app/code/community:/web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/app/code/core:/web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/lib:.:/php5/lib/php/')  in /web/htdocs/www.dolcefuoco.com/home/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

And here autoload.php function that is creating problem:

```
 * Register SPL autoload function
 */
static public function register()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array(self::instance(), 'autoload'));
}

/**
 * Load class source code
 *
 * @param string $class
 */
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile = $class;
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    //echo $classFile;die();
    return include $classFile;
}
```

Line 93 is:

```
return include $classFile;
```

What can I do to fix it? Any Suggestion is very appreciated, the site is down!!

Comment: What changes were you making?

Comment: I disabled the Tag module, and wrongly disabled the Mage_Admin.
I figured out that i disable the Mage_admin only after clicking the save button. Once done the site went down. Then I enabled it again. But nothing happened. i don't know if this Mage_admin has an impact or not but every happened after this edit i made.

Comment: There is something else going on. Disabling `Mage_Admin` will not take the site down. And, depending on your version, `Mage_Admin` will not even disable your admin. I think there is something else going on coincidentally. Chances are there is another module that is causing the problems. `Mage_Http:_Helper` is a broken reference to `Mage_Core_Helper_Http`. Have you installed anything recently?

Comment: No the site was working great. i did not installed anything in the past days. I made some changes to the footer, but I did some test after the editing and the site was live and working. I just noticed on phpmyadmin that the DB exceded the max size we paid for. And I just asked for an upgrade of the db size. Could this error related to the db or something like that?

Comment: IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO DISABLE A MODULE THROUGH THE ADMIN - it is only possible to disable module *output* (like the group name suggests). Not sure how many times this has to be said, but hopefully people will take note.

Comment: I don't think the db needing more space would cause the problem. What kind of extensions do you have running? I was able to duplicate the exact error with the following code: `var_dump(Mage::helper('http://stackoverflow.com'));` This would make good sense that some how, and for some crazy reason, a url is being passed into the helper factory function.

Comment: Thanks JMax for the help you're providing. I'm very new to Magento. There is no Extension manager installed, how can I check which extensions are running?

Comment: I'm also trying to completely overwrite the "app" folder wit the backup saved yesterday (in case I did somethign wrong with some page code) but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you provide a few more lines of your callstack?  The code you've pointed to is used all over the magento system.  It's almost impossible for anyone to help with the information provided.

Comment: Hi Alan, I copied the entire mage.php code and pasted above. Hope it helps. Please let me know if anything else could help you in understanding the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't very helpful, as every Magento installation has that file, and are all very similar through the versions. Can you look in your error/php logs to see if there is a better stack trace. Magento has roughly 2.5 million lines of PHP, and the `Mage::helper('')` method is called many a time through there.

Comment: ok, I posted the log warning and the function that is creating problem. Do you need anything else?

Comment: It will not help. Try install the same magento version as you have and compare your files with it. There should be invalid `Mage::helper()` call somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Does your config.xml reference any helpers? (any custom addition/changes that have been made)

If so, the path/settings in there may be incorrect or something could be missing that is needed.